# Tail Recursion in C?

Tags: c, tail-recursion

I have two concerns,

1. Can a tail recursive function have more than 2 arguments?
2. The below implementation in an exponential function, a base it
   raised to its power, is there other way that I can further improve
   the function below?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m,int n, int o);
int powerAux(int m, int n);    
main() {
    printf("%d\n", powerAux(2,3));
}
int power(int m, int n, int o) {
    if (o == 1) {
        return m;
    }
    return power(m*n, n, o - 1);
}
int powerAux(int m, int n) {
    return power(m, m, n);
}
```

Comment: I will output a wrong value, because when we pass in (2,3)
The function will be,
(2*2,2)
(4*4,1)
which is 16, the correct answer is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely improve your function's efficiency by implementing fast multiplication algorithm:

```
int exp(int base, int pow) {
    if (pow == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (pow%2 == 0) {
        int temp = exp(base, pow/2);
        return temp*temp;
    } else {
        int temp = exp(base, (pow-1)/2);
        return temp*temp*base;
    }
}
```

We use temp value not to count same value twice with recursion.

Comment: This solution causes an infinite loop

Comment: added forgotten quit statement. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this faster compared to the previous solution, we are doing division and extra modulus check, but the original solution only does multiplication to find the answer?

Comment: @naveenath Your code loops `n` times; this solution only loops `log n` times (it basically iterates over the bits in the exponent).

Comment: @naveenath it's [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), and has better complexity than simple multiplications

Comment: Try `int exp(1, 0)`  - infinite loop

Comment: It's just the idea not the solution of his problem. It's stack overflow - not solutions service.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sure, why not?
2. Your function doesn't handle an exponent of `0`. Your base case should be changed to:

   ```
   if (o == 0) {
       return m;
   }
   ```

   and your accumulator initialized to `1`:

   ```
   return power(1, m, n);
   ```

   Also, `n` / `o` should probably be changed to `unsigned` because your code doesn't handle negative exponents (and it can't without changing to non-integral types).